# xz archive opens in linux, corrupted in windows

Tags: windows, file-corruption, xz

I have some xz archives (that were created in Linux), I can decompress them fine in linux but I'm trying to open them in Windows (7).  I've used both 7zip and ExtractNow.  In both cases the archive opens ok but when I extract the file it says it's corrupted and it creates a zero byte file.  Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: ExtractNow uses 7-Zip libraries ([source](http://www.extractnow.com/Usage.aspx)), so there's a decent chance that this is a result of a bug or a missing feature in 7-Zip. TO be able to give you a better answer than "decent chance", I'd need access to the archive. Is it too big or too private to share it?

Comment: I worked out that the problem was to do with ascii mangling getting the data off the ftp server.  Setting the transfer to binary sorted it out.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Perfect example of why it's always important to include all information in your question, no matter how irrelevant it seems.

Comment: You live and learn... Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by OP in comments of OP

I worked out that the problem was to do with ascii mangling getting the data off the ftp server. Setting the transfer to binary sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you may try xz below `cygwin`.